# Angularjs Argument is not a function got string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modularity

I am a newbie to angularjs.  I am building an application where my home page will have a list of posts.  I thought of using angularjs for two way binding for that page alone.  I started with a sample page but ran into issues here itself.

My sample page.  I am using ng-app for this div alone as i dont want angularjs to interact with any other aspects of the page.

```
<div ng-app="posts">
  <ul class="post_list" ng-controller="PostController">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
    {{post.title}}
    {{post.description}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i have a app.js file which has

```
var app = angular.module('posts', []);
```

and a postcontroller.js file with

```
(function(angular, app) {
  // Define the Controller as the constructor function.
  console.log(app);
  console.log(angular);
  app.controller("PostController",["$scope"], function($scope) {
    $scope.posts = [
      {"title":"asdf", "description":"describe"},
      {"title":"second one", "description":"second describe"},
    ];
  });
})(angular, app);
```

When i load my home page. I am getting

> Error: argument "PostController" is not a function. got string 
>   [googlecdn path]angular.min.js:16

What am i missing here.  Please help me as i am totally confused.  I am new to angularjs and also to javascript.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are declaring your controller. You should do it like shown below:

```
app.controller("PostController",["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.posts = [
      {"title":"asdf", "description":"describe"},
      {"title":"second one", "description":"second describe"},
    ];
  }]);
```

Please notice that the second argument is an array with both a `$scope` string and a function as array's elements. This is a proper syntax to be used to write minification-safe code.

Comment: worked fine after these changes.  Can you point me to some resource which explains why this syntax works with minimification?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @R.A.J have a look at the "Dependency Annotation" section in http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Minification mangles function and argument names but not String literals.

Comment: This answer helped me, but my issue was the closing "]" wasn't at the end of the controller instead at the end of the injections.  Ooops.  :)